# Keeping a latent file-handle

Tags: c++, windows, file-io, ofstream

I am writing a time-critical application in C++ where I write data to a log which is constantly displayed and updated in the web-browser (I can't change this, please do not recommend to use a different solution).

At the moment I do something like this every 100ms to dump the data (the **whole file** has to be rewritten each dump):

```
ofstream log_file(log_path);
//Do some error handling
log_file << "Quite some data" << endl;
log_file.close();
```

The problem is that every few calls the program needs like ~20msec to open the log and it seems to cause a lot of hdd usage on some systems (I suspect the hdd is seeking the file again on every reopen process).

Is there a way to keep the file handle open all the time so the system hopefully keeps some pointer to the file to minimize the delays and hdd usage? I will gladly switch to a different Write-API too if that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your log file on a in-memory filesystem, such as `/dev/shm`. That will avoid accessing the disks, unless the log file is too big to fit there.

Comment: Maybe I should say that it is a windows application.

Comment: Well the idea is still good, I looked around and found a way to do it for windows so this still answers my question.